# Getting a swf's bytes from within the swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to implement some security mechanism in AS3 targeting Flash (not AIR). I would like to get the actual binary content (as a ByteArray) of the swf my code is running in.
If I look at `stage.loaderInfo.bytesTotal`, it correctly contains the length of the swf file; I was expecting `stage.loaderInfo.bytes` to contain the actual content, but this ByteArray is much larger than the swf itself, so

- what does stage.loaderInfo.bytes actually contain? (the doc is not explicit at all)
- is there a way to get the swf's bytes as I would need? (other than re-loading the swf through a URLLoader)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `stage.loaderInfo.bytes` contains the uncompressed SWF data. In most SWFs, the first few bytes or so contain a little uncompressed binary data and the rest of the SWF is compressed. You can refer to the [spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf) for more info on that. I would expect that `bytes` would contain this uncompressed header data followed by the rest of the SWF data, now decompressed.

As a sidenote, [`bytesTotal`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#bytesTotal) gives you the compressed length, which is why it shows you the value you expect.

One possible way to reconstruct the compressed SWF would just be to compress the part of the data from `bytes` with the appropriate algorithm, which is actually indicated by the very first byte of the SWF. What do you need the actual data for?

Comment: Good guess, I just found out that swf's are usually ZLIB'ed. 
My need is to validate that the content of the swf has not been altered, and the check has to be made from within the swf. But knowing that the bytes are compressed, I just have to uncompress them before creating the reference.

Comment: Yep, seems like that should work. If you're compiling with Flex, I know the compiler has an option for compression (see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html). I would guess that whatever method you're using to compile your SWF would have something similar, might be useful for you anyways

Answer (score 0):

We still have limited scope for IO in Flash; references to "Loader" or more specific to the idea of "root" (which you can still use) - this would only be assuming your binary data object is acceccable to the SWF at page level. You seemed to be looking more for the 1-2 on how Flash parses Byte Arrays.

It's a long topic, and has been over-discussed [in my opinion], but since Flash uses AMF and instantiates customs objects from any host, there is a large set of Classes available that are Native AS 3.0 (no AIR or Flex needed) - that can be used for reading, writing, and encoding binary.

Below is an example class I wrote not too long ago for a Jr developer who needed a  quick understanding of how serialization works in AS 3.0 - I hope it helps:

```
     package {
         import flash.display.*; 
         import flash.net.*; 
         import flash.events.*;
         import flash.utils.*;

         public class loadAndRead extends EventDispatcher {
              private var ldr:Loader;
              private var urq:URLRequest;
              private var iba:ByteArray; 
              private var swf:String;
              private var obj:*;
        function loadAndRead() {
              ldr = new Loader();
              urq = new URLRequest(swf = 'anyswfanywhere.swf');
        }
        public function rd(d:*):void { 
              obj = d;
              iba = obj['BTS'] as ByteArray() || ByteArray(obj['BTS']); 
              iba.uncompress()
              iba.deflate();
              iba.readUTFBytes();
              iba.position       = 0;
              iba.uncompress(); 
              iba.position       = 0;
              for each (var n:* in i.readObject())
                        {
                         if(n){trace(i.readObject()['n']+": "+n)
                        }
               }  
        } 
        private function getSWF():void {
            ldr.load(urq); 
            ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ogs); 
        }
        private function ogs(w:Event):void { 
        rd({L: ldr.contentLoaderInfo.bytes.length,
            A: ldr.contentLoaderInfo.bytes.bytesAvailable,
            T: ldr.contentLoaderInfo.contentType,
                    U: ldr.contentLoaderInfo.loaderURL, 
                   BA: ldr.contentLoaderInfo.bytes.readUTF(), 
                  BTS: ldr.contentLoaderInfo.bytes 
                  });
      }  
  } 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. BTW In the AS3 world, to be verbose is to be a better coder. It is no longer the days of 256KB of ram.